# Dropdown menu not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu

I'm stuck with my dropdown menu.
I want it to open when I click the Nav-Button "clicker". Then it shall close when I click "clicker" again.

I want it to show/hide only when clicking the Image. It shall stay open when I click inside the hidden div.

But that doesnt work. I dont know why. Tried so many things. Any idea? (Total noob here).

HTML:
(Click on "#clicker" Image = Toggle Dropdown; "#dropdown-inside" = hidden div;

```
<div class="header_content">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div id="dropdown-menu">
      <img id="clicker" src="http://porschedvd.de/bluptest/typo3/fileadmin/stromer/template/pix/menu_btn.jpg" alt="">
       <ul id="dropdown-inside">
```

JQuery:

```
$j('#clicker').click(function() {
$j('#clicker').not(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow");

$j(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
});


$j('#clicker').blur(function() {
$j('#dropdown-inside').hide('slow', function() {
});
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/377G6/2/

Comment: `#clicker` is an image, it's a self closing element that can't have children.

Comment: @adeneo You just close the img-element when developing for an xhtml doctype.

Comment: @WoIIe - Doesn't matter if you close or not, it's ***self closing***, it has no children.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/377G6/3/

Comment: you should use `.next()` instead of `.children()`

Comment: u mean on click => show Dropdown,again click ,hide ?

Comment: Thank you. both solutions work like charm!

Comment: toggles in ur code not working as per fiddle

Comment: @MohitArora , please post ur fiddle  in answer section.So it will be good for future visitors

Comment: @PratikJoshi i think Edisonator already post good answer :)

Comment: @MohitArora , yes  ,  so I did +1 ,See , these are talented newbies.please dont hesitate to +1 if answer is correct,and given by someone with 11 reputation :) .thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have read your code and tried to run it.
Now you have 2 points to fix:

1. Your selector `$j(this).children(ul)` can't find the list.

   The list `ul` is a sibling element of your `#clicker`, so you can use the method `siblings('ul')` or `next()` to select the list, but not `children()`
2. the event 'blur' can't be triggered now.

   Generally, the event `blur` could only be triggered on `input` or `textarea`, so if you want to trigger the `blur` on `<img>` or `<div>`, you may set an attribute like `tabindex="-1"` to it.

As I tried, it runs successfully after the fix.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/edisonator/kfcB9/

Thanks,
Edison

Comment: Can you please post jsfiddle for same ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi I have add it for same, it is : http://jsfiddle.net/edisonator/kfcB9/  Could you forgive me and cancel the reduce of my vote?

Comment: Ok , but remember ,dont post Theoratical answers on S.overflow, The answers are important for future visitors.Would u like if u r in urgent Coding scenario and u just see Informative/Theoratical code?Thanks

Comment: That works! With the solutions in my posts comments it worked fine, except in the Safari Browser. But Edisonator's code fixed it. It's working now on all my tested browsers and mobile devices.